# Dynamic allocation of an array of structs does not work

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to dynamically allocate an array of structs but everytime i read the data of the struct it prints some random characters before the print statement. For example if input JOHN as the first name it will print J O before the print statement and sometimes it also skips some scanf statements. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct DEP
    {
        char name[30];
        char rank;
        int number;

    };
    struct DEP *members;
    int size, i;

    scanf("%d", &size);
    members = malloc(size * sizeof(struct DEP));
    if(members == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    for(i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {
        fgets(members[i].name, 30, stdin);
        members[i].name[strcspn(members[i].name, "\n")] = '\0';
        scanf("%c %d", &members[i].rank, &members[i].number);
        printf("%s\n%c\n%d\n", members[i].name, members[i].rank, members[i].number);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

And an example of input:
[image]

Comment: `scanf("%d", &temp3);` doesn't read the newline added by the `Enter` you probably pressed after the input. Think about what happens when the first character that `fgets` read is a newline.

Comment: By the way, you don't need your `temp` variable, you can read directly into the structure members, as in `scanf("%d", &members[i].number);`

Comment: Checking the return value from `scanf()` would tell you if it successfully read any data or not.

Comment: regarding: `if(members == NULL)
    {
        return 1;`  Code should always inform the user about what is going on.  Especially when an error occurs.  Such error messages should be output to `stderr`.  When the error comes from a C library function should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.  Suggest: `if(members == NULL) { perror( "malloc failed" ); return 1; }`

Comment: regarding: `int size, i, temp3;`  the call to `malloc()` expects a parameter of type: `size_t`  and the `for()` statement is comparing `size` and `i` therefore, this line should be: `int temp3;   size_t size, i;`

Comment: given the above comments, this: `scanf("%d", &size);`  should be: `if( scanf("%lu", &size) != 1) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for -size- failed\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE );}`  The posted code also fails to inform the user that they need to enter the number of members

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%c %d", &members[i].rank, &members[i].number);`  This fails to tell the user that they need to enter `rank` and `number`  AND fails to check that the call to `scanf()` was successful

Comment: Please do not edit the posted code.  Rather post an EDIT'd version

Comment: You need to take care of the new line characters left in the buffer after scanf. That should fix your problem, I think.
`int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` after scanf...

Comment: Call memset after malloc as to set the Memory as NULL:

     memset(members, 0x00, (size * sizeof(struct DEP)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I added some print statements in your code while running at my end.

I did the below to get rid of the '\n' left in the buffer after scanf; and it yielded me good result. That's what is the root of the issue, I reckon. Unclean buffer.

```
int c;
while ((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

Modified the program as below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    struct DEP
    {
        char name[30];
        char rank;
        int number;

    };
    struct DEP *members;
    int size, i, c;

    scanf("%d", &size);
    members = malloc(size * sizeof(struct DEP));
    if(members == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    for(i = 0;i < size;i++)
    {
        printf ("Enter Name: \n");
        fgets(members[i].name, 30, stdin);
        members[i].name[strcspn(members[i].name, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf ("Enter rank and number: ");
        scanf("%c %d", &members[i].rank, &members[i].number);
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
        printf("Name: %s\nRank: %c\nNum: %d\n", members[i].name, members[i].rank, members[i].number);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Got the following output --

```
$ ./main.out
3
Enter Name:
siddharth
Enter rank and number: z 5
Name: siddharth
Rank: z
Num: 5
Enter Name:
sid
Enter rank and number: s 6
Name: sid
Rank: s
Num: 6
Enter Name:
sidhh
Enter rank and number: e 8
Name: sidhh
Rank: e
Num: 8
```